# Get instance by file name for a file in ImageField

Tags: django

**Django 3.1.6**

```
class ResponsiveImage(models.Model):
    responsive_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=_raster_img_upload_to)
```

I want to find an instance by the image file_name:

```
file_name = 'img/raster/0a8449e7-8e50-4c02-853e-59a25592770d/img_144_96_fallback_3x_4.fallback'
ResponsiveImage.objects.get(responsive_image__name=file_name)
```

But this gets an error:

```
{FieldError}Unsupported lookup 'name' for ImageField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an `ImageField` is saved the string for the relative path to the image is stored in the database for your `ResponsiveImage` object for the field `responsive_image`.

You should be able to just go

```py
ResponsiveImage.objects.get(responsive_image=file_name)
```

To get a specific `ResponsiveImage` object (As long as it actually exists in the database).